# .NET library for Reed-Solomon errata (errors+erasures) decoding

Tags: library, c#, .net

I'm looking for a Reed-Solomon coding library for .NET. I've seen many people suggesting the Reed-Solomon component of the [ZXing.Net](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Source/lib/common/reedsolomon) library, but that's not an option for me because it doesn't support erasure (known error locations) decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a library that takes the Reed-Solomon component of the ZXing.Net project, and added support for [erasure and errata decoding](https://github.com/Sonic-The-Hedgehog-LNK1123/ReedSolomon).